# variables in sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, sp-executesql

I have a piece of code:

```
DECLARE @v int;  
DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(500);  
DECLARE @max_title varchar(30);  

SET @IntVariable = 197;  
SET @SQLString = N'SELECT @max_titleOUT = max(JobTitle)   
   FROM some_table 
   WHERE name = @level';  
SET @ParmDefinition = N'@level tinyint, @max_titleOUT varchar(30) OUTPUT';  

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLString, @ParmDefinition, @level = @v, @max_titleOUT=@max_title OUTPUT;  
SELECT @max_title;
```

I'm a little bit confused about this line:

```
       WHERE name = @level';
```

If `@v` is a string instead of an `int` variable, should I put quotes around `@level` like this?

```
       WHERE name = ''@level''';
```

When should I put quotes around a variable inside the `@SQLString`?

Answer (score 2):

No, `@level` and `@v` are variables. You shouldn't put quotes around.

> When should I put quotes around a variable inside the @SQLString?

Nowhere

Comment: Even `name` is of nvarchar(...) type? Generally we will write statements like `WHERE name = '...'`, right?

Comment: @OgrishMan don't miss, that `@level` is a variable. When you write `WHERE name = @level` not in `sp_executesql ` you don't put quotes, right? So, no need to put them in `sp_executesql `

Comment: Oh, yes! Thank you for the explanation. I'm clear now but I don't know why I feel confused about this just now. Thanks again!

Comment: @OgrishMan glad to help, maybe you just need time to get used to it